# how to loop throgh array of object from axios json respone in react js and set them in div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, loops, foreach

I am new to react js, I am trying to fetch the data from the DB and display it on a webpage. successfully fetched the data from DB as JSON using Axios, but I don't know how to loop the object inside the array. I tried to use the map function but it's not working because of response has multiple objects in a single array. can anyone help me to fix this?

this is my json

```
    {
    "selva": [
        {
            "cus_id": "1",
            "name": "selva",
            "loc_name": "chennai",
            "loc_phone": "986478393",
            "loc_email": "selva@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "cus_id": "1",
            "name": "selva",
            "loc_name": "Trichy",
            "loc_phone": "123456789",
            "loc_email": "surya@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "ram": [
        {
            "cus_id": "3",
            "name": "ram",
            "loc_name": "tnager",
            "loc_phone": "45654345",
            "loc_email": "ram@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "Sam": [
        {
            "cus_id": "4",
            "name": "Sam",
            "loc_name": "chrompet",
            "loc_phone": "234545634",
            "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "cus_id": "4",
            "name": "Sam",
            "loc_name": "mount",
            "loc_phone": "234545634",
            "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "cus_id": "4",
            "name": "Sam",
            "loc_name": "adambakkam",
            "loc_phone": "45654345",
            "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is how I fetched the data in react js and stored in array

```
    componentDidMount(){
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("f_SearchWord", "null");
    const url = "http://localhost/cusPHP/dashAllCustomer.php";
    const config = {
      headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
    };
    axios.post(url, formData, config).then((result) => { 
     this.setState({jData: result.data})   
    });

  }
```

this is the output I am looking for on the webpage, one customer name, multiple phones, email, location in one div, next customer on next div.

[image: OUTPUT]

this is the react page code

```
<div className="commodities">
                <div className="grid-x">
                  <div className="cell large-12">
                    <h2>Customers</h2>
                     
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="grid-x small-up-12">

                { 
                     


                 //loop the data
                  
                }
                  <div className="cell">
                    <div className="callout">
                      <div className="grid-x">
                        <div className="cell large-3">
                          <h3>name</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div className="cell large-9">
                          <div className="table-break">
                            <div className="grid-x">
                              <div className="cell medium-4">
                                <div className="grid-x">
                                  <div className="cell large-12">
                                    <span>location name</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-3">
                                <span>Phone Number</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-3">
                                <span>Email Address</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-2">
                                <input
                                  type="button"
                                  className="label label-button float-right"
                                  value="Edit"
                                  onClick={this.EdittogglePopup}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className="table-break">
                            <div className="grid-x">
                              <div className="cell medium-4">
                                <div className="grid-x">
                                  <div className="cell large-12">
                                    <span>location name</span>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-3">
                                <span>Phone Number</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-3">
                                <span>Email Address</span>
                              </div>
                              <div className="cell medium-2">
                                <input
                                  type="button"
                                  className="label label-button float-right"
                                  value="Edit"
                                  onClick={this.EdittogglePopup}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: are you getting proper response from "jData"?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through them like this:

```
{this.state.jData && Object.keys(this.state.jData).map(key => (
  <>
    {this.state.jData[key].map(data => (
      <div className="cell large-3">
        <h3>{data.name}</h3>
      </div>
    ))}
  </>
))}
```

Comment: getting TypeError: jData[key].map is not a function.

Comment: Please check edited code

Comment: thanks bro its working, now i can set the data in particular field

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate an object. Hence you cannot directly use "map" as an option. You can try as below to iterate:

```js
var jData = {
  "selva": [{
      "cus_id": "1",
      "name": "selva",
      "loc_name": "chennai",
      "loc_phone": "986478393",
      "loc_email": "selva@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "cus_id": "1",
      "name": "selva",
      "loc_name": "Trichy",
      "loc_phone": "123456789",
      "loc_email": "surya@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "ram": [{
    "cus_id": "3",
    "name": "ram",
    "loc_name": "tnager",
    "loc_phone": "45654345",
    "loc_email": "ram@gmail.com"
  }],
  "Sam": [{
      "cus_id": "4",
      "name": "Sam",
      "loc_name": "chrompet",
      "loc_phone": "234545634",
      "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "cus_id": "4",
      "name": "Sam",
      "loc_name": "mount",
      "loc_phone": "234545634",
      "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "cus_id": "4",
      "name": "Sam",
      "loc_name": "adambakkam",
      "loc_phone": "45654345",
      "loc_email": "sam@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
};

Object.keys(jData).map(val => {
  jData[val].map(cusData => {
    //Print your data here
    console.log(cusData['loc_name']);
    console.log(cusData['loc_phone']);
  });
});
```

This is an idea to iterate your object. But please make sure your json is not too large. Otherwise it'll hit your performance and then you might have to find alternative way to print your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
export default function DetailTable({data}) {

  return (
      <div className="grid-x small-up-12">
        <BuildDetailTable data={data} />
      </div>
    );
}

const BuildDetailTable = ({ data }) => {
  const result = [];
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    result.push(
      <div className="cell">
        <div className="callout">
          <div className="grid-x">
            <div className="cell large-3">
              <h3>{key}</h3>
              <BuildDetailRow data={value} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return result;
};

const BuildDetailRow = ({ data }) => {
  const result = [];
  for (const item of data) {
    result.push(
      <div className="cell large-9">
        <div className="table-break">
          <div className="grid-x">
            <div className="cell medium-4">
              <div className="grid-x">
                <div className="cell large-12">
                  <span>Name: {item.loc_name}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="cell medium-3">
              <span>Phone: {item.loc_phone}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cell medium-3">
              <span>Email: {item.loc_email}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="cell medium-2">
              <input
                type="button"
                className="label label-button float-right"
                value="Edit"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return result;
};
```

Is you pass the api data to `DetailTable` component, it will render the desired result

```
<DetailTable data={data from api}/>
```

The output I get is:

[image]

Comment: I am getting errors in  BuildDetailTable when it gets rendered, so I tried {this.BuildDetailTable(jData)} and removing the const before the name of the function the errors are gone, but I am getting Cannot convert undefined or null to object. so I tried the console log it showed the output first line as [],  next line with the data fetched from DB.

Comment: This is an entire component by itself, you have to put it in a separate file, import them into your class component and use it. Pass the data as props, make sure data exist before rendering the component, thats all you have to do

Comment: Are you initialising the state with empty array instead of object?

Comment: thanks, bro for your help I got that working, in the feature I will ask for your help because I am new to react js. Learning one by one!